# Create SQL Server temporary tables inside Python script

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, pymssql, pypyodbc

I'm using pypyodbc to connect to the SQL Server. I want to store my resultset into a temporary table like we do in SQL. But everytime I try to do it - I get this error message:

> pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('24000', '[24000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver]Invalid cursor state')

This is what I'm trying to query:

```
querytest = "SELECT id into #temp from Team"
cursor1.execute(querytest);
var = cursor1.fetchall()
print(var[:10])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query

```sql
SELECT id into #temp from Team
```

does not return a result set; it just creates the `#temp` table. You now need to SELECT from the `#temp` table in order to see the results, i.e., something like

```python
querytest = "SELECT id into #temp from Team"
cursor1.execute(querytest);  # no result set returned
cursor1.execute("SELECT id FROM #temp")  # result set returned here
var = cursor1.fetchall()
print(var[:10])
```